# MapStruct: How to convert a POJO into multiple entities according to a array field

Tags: java, mapstruct

POJO:

```
public class TestDto {
    private List<String> idList;
    private String name;
}
```

entity:

```
public class Test {
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

If `TestDto`'s `idList` is `1, 2, 3` , `name` is `abc` , how can I get 3 corresponding `Test` entities by MapStruct ?

Answer (score 0):

MapStruct cannot perform this mapping for you. However, you can play with multiple source properties to achieve something like this:

e.g.

```
@Mapper
public interface TestMapper {


    default List<Test> map(TestDto dto) {
        if (dto == null || dto.getIdList() == null) {
            return null;
        }

        List<String> idList = dto.getIdList();
        List<Test> tests = new ArrayList<>(idList.size());
        for (String id: idList) {
            tests.add(map(id, dto);
        }

        return tests;
    }

    Test map(String id, TestDto dto);

}
```